# gorm query does not return contents of the table referenced by a foreign key

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two entities defined as this:

```
type Person struct {
    Id          string `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
    Firstname   string `json:"firstname" binding:"required"`
    Lastname    string `json:"lastname" binding:"required"`
    PhoneNumber string `json:"phoneNumber"`
    Email       string `json:"email" binding:"email"`
}

type Tenancy struct {
    Id                int `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
    TenantId          int
    Tenant            Person    `json:"tenant" binding:"required" gorm:"foreignKey:TenantId"`
    StartDate         time.Time `json:"start-date" binding:"required"`
    EndDate           time.Time `json:"end-date" binding:"required"`
}
```

The tenancy type's TenantId field is a foreign key that references the Person type.

My PostgresSQL tables are created using:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lastname     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    phone_number VARCHAR(30),
    email        VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE tenancy
(
    id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    tenant_id           INT  NOT NULL,
    start_date          DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date            DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_person FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES person (id)
);
```

I tried to retrieve a tenancy as well as the tenant using gorm:

```
err := db.Table("tenancy").Where("id=?", id).Find(&tenancy).Error
```

The result I get back is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "TenantId": 1,
    "tenant": {
        "id": "",
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "email": ""
    },
    "start-date": "2023-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end-date": "2024-10-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I expect all the fields in the tenant section are populated, but they are left empty.

I also tried this gorm line:

```
err := db.Table("tenancy").Preload("Tenant").Where("id=?", id).First(&tenancy).Error
```

But it returns an error:

```
relation "people" does not exist
```

What can I do to retrieve the tenancy table and the contents of the person table at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out that the problem is due to the naming convention of gorm.

gorm expects the table names to be pluriazed. Therefore, I need to change my database table name of person to people, and change tenancy to tenancies.

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lastname     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    phone_number VARCHAR(30),
    email        VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE tenancies
(
    id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    tenant_id           INT  NOT NULL,
    start_date          DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date            DATE NOT NULL,
    length_in_months    INT  NOT NULL,
    has_breaking_clause BOOLEAN,
    rent                FLOAT,
    agent               VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT fk_people FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES people (id)
);
```

The golang statement below works fine:

```
err := db.Preload("Tenant").Where("id=?", id).First(&tenancy).Error
```

The result is now:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "TenantId": 1,
    "tenant": {
        "id": "1",
        "firstname": "Tom",
        "lastname": "Jerry",
        "phoneNumber": "1234567",
        "email": "abc@hotmail.com"
    },
    "start-date": "2023-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end-date": "2024-10-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```